Can anyone name this animated robot movie from the 80's/90's? Please?
I was born in '91, so this movie would have to have been out in the 80's/90's. I remember it being on VHS. I live in the US, the movie was in English. It was an animated children's film. It was in color.
There were three robots (a girl robot, a boy robot, and a smaller robot) that were running from an evil robot and ended up in a town and hid in a kids house.
All of the robots used music like magic. The evil robot's music could hypnotize people.
I want to say that the good robots were powered by happiness or love? The robots were more cutesy. I want to say that they had hearts on their chests, but that may be incorrect. 
Other things I remember:

It was definitely aimed at younger children, under ten or so.
It wasn't a musical, they just used music, if that makes sense. 
I remember the movie starts with the good robots running through trees away from the bad one. They end up finding a town and hiding in a garage. * I think it's a little boy that helps them. Maybe 7 or 8 years old?
The evil robot uses music to hypnotize the towns people.
In a very "tinker bell" kind of way, the good robots start to lose power because there is no love.
I want to say that one of them played a trumpet? 

I don't remember the animation being anime-esque, so I'm assuming it was more an American style of animation. It doesn't stand out in my mind as lower quality that anything else I watched around then. 

Do you remember more about it, e. g. the look of the robots (cute, angular, anthropomorphic, large, small, colors etc.?) and how old were the children they were hiding at? What audience did it aim at? How important was the music (was the movie more of a musical)? Was the style typical of American or Japanese cartoons (or even different from them)? Was the animation of good quality (in general, or for its time)? Do you remember more about the plot - where adults involved etc.? Everything can help.

I edited the post to add absolutely every detail I can think of.

From your description and from my hazy memories. I believe it was called "Robotman and Friends-Straight from the heart". Hope this was the show you were looking for :-) 

Please add script or a relevant video to confirm that this is the movie the original poster is looking for.

That is correct and completely what I was looking for! Thank you guys so very much! This has been bothering me for years!
